# Múltiple consulta con múltiples resultados en SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Buenos días, tengo una gran duda sobre unas consultas que debo realizar para conseguir unos resultados en PHP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando realizo la consulta en PHP queda dentro del código así:

```
<?php $qry = "SELECT pro, pro_jornada, pro_cupos_proyectados
                         FROM proy";
                        $pro = consult($qry);
                        $data["PRO"] = $pro;
                        foreach($data["PRO"] as $dato){
                            $pro = $dato["pro"];
                            $pro_jornada = $dato["pro_jornada"];
                            $pro_cupos_proyectados = $dato["pro_cupos_proyectados"];?>
                        <p>PRO: <?php echo $pro;?></p>
                        <p>Jornada: <?php echo $pro_jornada;?></p>
                        <p>Cupos Dipo: <?php echo $pro_cupos_proyectados;?></p>
                        <br><br>
                        <?php }?>
```

**Dentro de la página me arroja un resultado en regular que tiene el mismo número "PRO" y quisiera lograr unificarlo, pero la verdad no logró entender como hacerlo y si se puede conseguir como se muestra en el recuadro verde, agradecería cualquier ayuda o cualquier recomendación dentro del código y gracias de antemano!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu SGBD? Este tipo de cosas se logran mejor con funciones de agregación.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, estoy usando PGADMIN de PostgreSQL

Comment: Entonces revisa las [funciones de agregación de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-aggregate.html) te serán de mucha utilizad para casos como estos.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy escribiendo el codigo a ciegas, pero algo así podría funcionar, la clave está en juntar los datos similares en un array y luego presentarlos haciendo uso de un método como implode(), que permite mostrar un array en un string usando un string como separador.

```
<?php 
    $qry = "SELECT pro, pro_jornada, pro_cupos_proyectados FROM proy";
    $pro = consult($qry);
    $data["PRO"] = $pro;
    foreach($data["PRO"] as $dato){
      $pro = $dato["pro"];
      $pro_jornada[] = $dato["pro_jornada"];
      $pro_cupos_proyectados[$dato["pro_jornada"]] = $dato["pro_cupos_proyectados"];
    ?>
    <p>PRO: <?php echo implode(', ', $pro); ?></p>
    <p>Jornada: <?php echo implode(', ',$pro_jornada;);?></p>
    <p>Cupos Dipo: 
    <?php 
    foreach ($pro_cupos_proyectados as $clave => $valor) {
            echo "{$clave} => {$valor} ";
        }
    </p>
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, te quería comentar que el principal problema esta en la parte de la consulta, no dentro del código... de igual forma agradezco bastante tu respuesta y la implementaré en futuros casos que tengan que ver con ello! PD: Si necesitas mas información del código o alguna aclaración te la puedo dar